# iOS 8.3 - UITableView cell not aligned, indentation to the left

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios8.3

I've stumbled upon a strange behaviour, where cells added to a `UITableView` were sometimes indented to the left. This only happens on iOS 8.3, and I can't find a clear pattern as to when this happens.

Anyone experiencing same thing?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824830/has-anything-changed-with-custom-uitableview-prototype-cells-constraints-since-i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well - this is strange...

It seems that sometimes `UITableViewCellContentView`'s `contentView` is not aligned with the `UITableViewCellContentView` itself. This happens when the `UITableView` is in itself a part of a layout wider than the screen (as in the case of a horizontal pager).

Luckily, the solution is simple: add a constraint to align the `contentView` with its parent. This can only be done programatically, as you can not edit the `contentView`'s constraints in the layout editor.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    // iOS 8.3 bug, where contentView's x position isnt aligned with self's x position...
    // So we add a constraint to do the obvious...
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
}
```

This only started happening on iOS 8.3, but the fix seems to be safe and backward compatible to earlier versions as well.

As always - please comment with your own experience.

Comment: Not sure how you discovered this, but I'm very grateful for it. Many of my table cells were looking weird and I had no idea why. This fixed all of them. Thanks!

Comment: Happy I could provide some help.

Comment: So I noticed that while this seems to have fixed this issue when I'm building using the 8.3 SDK and running on 8.2, when I actually upgrade an iPad to 8.3, it persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: This solution relies on adding a constraint to fix the glitch. If it still persists on your device then something else if removing or affecting said constraint.

Comment: @Vaiden thanks for the answer. Where shall I put that code? In the view controller containing the UITableView or somewhere else?

Comment: I tried to add it to each cell awakeFromNib but it would not work.. any idea why?

Comment: Try the solution from @medmonds instead

Comment: tried in updateConstraints and awakeFromNib but not working. its crashing

Answer (score 13):

My tableViewCells were seeing increased left and right margins when run on iOS 8.3 that I did not see on previous versions.

Setting:

```
    self.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
```

fixed my problem and kept my margins consistent on all versions but be aware that this in only available on iOS 8+.

So here, for example, is where you might do this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if ([self.contentView respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        self.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Just wrapped it in an `if(respondsToSelector)` check in `awakeFromNib` and it stopped the extra indentation.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing!   Could you tell me how to fix if I don't use storyboard?

self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        self.tableView!.delegate = self
        self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Thanks

Comment: This helped with an issue I had when testing a tableView UI glitch in iOS 11 that wasn't there in iOS 10 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's because of [layoutMargins](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins) property. I've unchecked my constraint second item "Relative to margin" and everything worked great. Here is the [article](http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/ios8-layout-margins).

Comment: Thanks for the input. However I had no margin constraint and the issue begun with iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a variation of this issue with an app I'm working on. We're seeing some table view cells with incorrect leading/trailing alignment.

It's not connected to iOS 8.3, it only occurs when building with Xcode 6.3. I can take the same project and build it on Xcode 6.2 and it doesn't occur.

After some investigation, it turns out that this only occurs on the table view cells in xibs.

The workaround is to remove the leading/trailing constraint to margins and set them directly to the superview (i.e. the cell content view).

Comment: This must be a different issue then. The issue that I (OP) reported was experienced by users who upgraded from iOS 8.2 to 8.3, using our app version compiled and submitted from XCode 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed for me. I've just stopped using `UITableViewCell`'s `imageView` and `textLabel` properties reconnected to my outlets.