# Has anything changed with custom UITableView prototype cells constraints since iOS 8.3?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface, ios8.1, ios8.3

I have recently installed iOS 8.3 on my iPhone (I had iOS 8.1 before).

I also updated the iOS SDK from iOS 8.1 to iOS 8.3.

Since I updated it some custom prototype cells I had seem to be misplaced.

**Has anything changed from iOS 8.1 to iOS 8.3 regarding the way constraints are handled?**

---

**EDIT:**

I tried the solution suggested but does not work for me. Will add more details on my cells in few seconds.

I added this to the custom cell class:

```
-(void) updateConstraints{
    [super updateConstraints];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
}
```

This is the way it used to look:

[image]

This is the way it looks:

[image]

Comment: Very hard to tell what is the problem without seeing the constraints... I see that there is an issue in the posted code though - the `[super updateConstraints];` should be the last line in the method according to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed at least 1 discrepancy, and the talk around my issue seems to reveal more: [iOS 8.3 - UITableView cell not aligned, indentation to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572043/ios-8-3-uitableview-cell-not-aligned-indentation-to-the-left?noredirect=1#comment47811105_29572043)

Comment: Hello, I had seen your Question but unfortunately the solution does  not work for me. Have you seen my edit? Thanks